# What should I learn first?

Tags: обучение

I want to start learning the russian language. But I have a problem, I have no idea what to do! So my question is what should I tackle first? What is the easiest way to start learning russian?

Comment: there're enough textbooks composed by professionals based on methodical presentation of material, this is what in my opinion you need to focus on, and that would be the easiest, a no brainer way to start out

Comment: Welcome to Russian SE. The thing is that your question is not about Russian language per se so it's off-topic here. You can try your luck and Language Learners SE however I still think that it won't be accepted the without some editing - so I can not just port it there.

Comment: Also, this question is off-topic because it's too broad and by it's nature can not  have a single accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to start learning any language is to find a teacher or/and a course and join a target-language speaking community. Good books and motivation are also important.

Nowadays there is a possibility to study online via Skype, etc.

Self-study also helps, though not so efficiently as communicating people in Russian.

If you choose self-study, get a textbook and use it.

Also, youtube can be helpful, though there is not really much material for foreign students, but still you can watch something to your taste in Russian.

Switch your gadgets to the Russian interface, be curious about the names of everything around you in Russian, learn the reading rules and read aloud as much as you can, whisper every Russian word you see. Write and type Russian, read what you have written, learn useful words and phrases by heart.

Ask questions here. :)

Good luck!